# Create a windows service to sync remote folder with local PC

Tags: c#, http, rest, windows-services, synchronization

I want to create a windows service to sync remote folder location with local PC. the remote folder is in a form of web URL and can access via `HTTP REST`. Can someone guide me through how to implement this.?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

- First - create a windows server.
- Second - get it to read the URLs.
- Third - get it to write the content locally as it's being read.

Than come back to SO when you have specific questions.

Comment: I have created an application to browse the remote folder. it simply show content and allow to download files. now I need to create a windows client that sync content in remote folder.

Comment: +1... This probably should be comment... But it provides exact "guidance"...

Answer (score 0):

Read the data like below:-

```
string url =String.Format(
"http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/xml?address={0}&sensor=false", "Andheri West".Replace(" ", ",")
);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(url );
HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();
Stream outputStream = response.GetResponseStream();
StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(outputStream, Encoding.ASCII);
string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
response.Close();
outputStream.Close();
reader.Close();
```

No make changes accordingly on local, you can use xsd class generator or manipulate output as needed.

Having said that you will also need XML or JSON parser to work around the output.

As per one of your comments:-

```
"I have created an application to browse the remote folder. it simply show content  and allow to download files. now I need to create a windows client that sync content in remote folder."
```

If I understand correctly you are trying to automate this process and you have all the needed expertise as you have done it in application that you have created, if so there are various methods to do so a scheduled job / windows service is what you need.